# Stack around the variable 'yol ' was corrupted

Tags: c

i am a newbie programmer, and cant seem to understand why my array gets corrupted.
i have increased the size of arrays as people say here, but that didnt work.what do i do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
int sayac,loop,start,loop2,yon,loop3;
int yol[17];
loop3 = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
    yon = rand()%2;
for(loop = 0;loop<15;loop++){
yol[loop] = 0;
printf("%d ", yol[loop]);
}
printf("\n");
srand(time(NULL));
start = rand()%15;
yol[start]++;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",yol[1],yol[2],yol[3],yol[4],yol[5],yol[6],yol[7],yol[8],yol[9],yol[10],yol[11],yol[12],yol[13],yol[14]);
while(loop3 == 0){
    if(yon == 0){
      start--;
    yol[start%15]++;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",yol[1],yol[2],yol[3],yol[4],yol[5],yol[6],yol[7],yol[8],yol[9],yol[10],yol[11],yol[12],yol[13],yol[14]);

    yon = rand()%2;
    }

if(yon == 1){
    start++;
    yol[start%15]++;
  printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",yol[1],yol[2],yol[3],yol[4],yol[5],yol[6],yol[7],yol[8],yol[9],yol[10],yol[11],yol[12],yol[13],yol[14]);
    yon = rand()%2;
    }

if(yol[0]!=0&&yol[1]!=0&&yol[2]!=0&&yol[3]!=0&&yol[4]!=0&&yol[5]!=0&&yol[6]!=0&&yol[7]!=0&&yol[8]!=0&&yol[9]!=0&&yol[10]!=0&&yol[11]!=0&&yol[12]!=0&&yol[13]!=0&&yol[14]!=0){
    break;}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything that would indicate that this is C++, and you should avoid cross-tagging in general (C++ should be using container classes instead of raw arrays). But somewhere you are almost certainly writing to an index outside the bounds of `yol` (0 - 16).

Answer (score 6):

```
start = rand()%15;
```

So `start` can be 0.

In your while loop you are doing

```
start--;
```

So now start is -1 and you are accessing

```
start[-1]
```

Accessing array which is not within the bound leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: that makes sense, what can i do to prevent that?

Comment: @KaanOlmez start is anyways doing %15 why do it again you just use start as your array index

Comment: I want to do a circular array, where yol[15] and yol[0] are next to each other

Comment: @KaanOlmez I hope you know array is stored contiguously.

Comment: Yeah, I do. but i need to do it this way. But i think i found a way.Thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: @KaanOlmez no probs hope I answered your question

Answer (score 2):

When you do a modulo of a negative number, the result is also negative, so in some case your `start` may be negative, therefore your `yol[start%15]` may reach for a negative index in your array --> corruption.